# why does the inline-block not work when elements are inside <div>

Tags: html, css

I know this is very silly, but I don't seem to get it. Why doesn't `inline-block` work for elements inside a `<div>`. My first code works, but the second doesn't. The rest of the code that is not included is exactly the same between them.

**1st** (working)

```css
.blue, .green, .red {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Display Property</h1>
<p class="red">Red Paragraph </p>
<p class="green">Green Paragraph</p>
<p class="blue">Blue Paragraph</p>
```

**2nd** (not working)

```css
.blue, .green, .red {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Display Property</h1>
<div>
  <p class="red">Red Paragraph </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="green">Green Paragraph</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="blue">Blue Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple, you wrap them inside a `div` - which have the default `display: block`, so it break each `p` to a new line. Either you move all the `p` into a single `div`, or you override the `display` of the `div` to `inline-block` too

Comment: Beacuse in the 2nd demo, the three divs are with display block, and every diplay block div shows in a new line. and then, inside every div is a p element with display inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beacuse in the 2nd demo, the three divs are with display block, and every diplay block div shows in a new line. and then, inside every div is a p element with display inline-block

To work with the 2nd example of divs, you should use display: inline-block in divs: Demo below

See CSS box model:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model

Demo:

```css
.blue, .green, .red {
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Display Property</h1>
<div> <p class="red">Red Paragraph </p></div>
<div> <p class="green">Green Paragraph</p></div>
<div> <p class="blue">Blue Paragraph</p> </div>
```

Comment: Or simple move the classes to the appropriate wrapper `div`s, instead of the paragraph elements.